# how to get stronly typed local resource file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i really love the idea of it as i can create a folder for my user control, and make sub folder images, css, and put local resource file, so the whole thing is contained in one folder, and that makes it really efficient for me (management wise).
but the bugger is you cant get intellisence like global resource, so is it possible in any way ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK: ASP.NET and Visual Studio in their standard configuration can only do this for global resources.